# Calling class method on a class parameter

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to call a class method to run a Cocos2D scene. I have a game controller in which I will pass in different states (or layers for those familiar with Cocos2D). See the code below:

```
-(void)startGameWithState:(Class)s {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [s scene]];
}
```

The thing is, this is working fine but generates the following warning:

```
No '+scene' method found
```

As best as possible, I want to avoid having warnings so how do I fix this?

Update: This is what I did.

```
-(void)changeStateTo:(Class <GameState>)s {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [s scene]];
}
```

By having the GameState protocol define the +scene method, I don't get any warnings.

Comment: More info, the +scene belongs to the class that I pass in during runtime but the compiler won't know at compile time, hence the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just declare a protocol or abstract class with the `scene` class method so the compiler knows it exists.

Comment: I had thought of using protocols, but perhaps not in the way you were getting at. Anyway, I will update the question with the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that your generic type -- `Class` -- doesn't have a method called `scene`. If you're passing in states/layers, those must be of some actual class, right? You need to tell the compiler what class `s` actually is so that it can find the `scene` method in it.

Comment: I get that; read my comment. How do you tell the compiler that it will have the method during runtime so that it won't give me the warning?

Comment: `Class` is not a class in Objective-C; it's a type that can represent any class, like `id` for objects. There is no generic class that all classes belong to in Objective-C. I imagine you're thinking of Ruby, which otherwise has a very similar type system.

Comment: I am a ruby programmer, and I am aware that the compiler doesn't know that what I am passing in has a +scene method because it gives a warning at compile time, while the Class is passed at runtime. I am looking for a solution to overcome the warning; this code is working perfectly. I need to inform the compiler that I am aware of what I am doing so that it can stop giving the warning.

Answer (score -2):

If you will always pass concrete class the write

```
-(void)startGameWithState:(ConcreteClass*)s
```

If you will use different classes without any hierarchy between them use id to avoid the warning

```
-(void)startGameWithState:(id)s
```

The second method is not very good because if you will pass the incorrect class object to this method you'll get runtime error. But at the compiling state everything will be fine

If you know that every class passed will be derived from some base class with a `+(id) scene` method then pass the base class:

```
-(void)startGameWithState:(BaseClass*)s
```

Comment: I am not passing an instance of the class. I want to pass the class itself. This is because the +scene method is responsible for instantiating itself.